# Pandas find indices where rows in a groupby exceed x

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame X

```
IDs Distance Threshold
 1     5          4
 3     6          9
 1     4          4
 3     10         9
```

Where I have IDs and each ID has a threshold. Now I want to find the row indices where the distance is larger than the threshold

```
idx=X.groupby(['IDs'])['Distance']>X['Threshold']
```

does not work.

```
idx=X.groupby(['IDs'])['Distance'].transform(???)>X['Threshold']
```

I thought that would work with a `groupby` and `transform`. However, the `transform` needs a function and I have not found out a function returning just the value.
Can someone help me, I guess it should be easier than I think.

Thanks

EDIT:

Thank you all. It was quite late and therefore I missed the most easy solution you all mentioned. I thought I had to group by ID, but the Threshold was already given per row... :-)
What I learned -> Late night work seldom pays out
Thank you all

Comment: `df[df.Distance.gt(df.Threshold)].index`?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking for. Can you [edit] to include your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, are you looking for:

```
df.where(df['Distance'] > df['Threshold']).dropna()
```

output:

```
   IDs  Distance  Threshold
0  1.0       5.0        4.0
3  3.0      10.0        9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches:

1. You can use a lambda function to check when the distance is larger then the threshold:

   `X['larger'] = X.apply(lambda x: x[1]>x[2],axis=1)`
2. You can use `np.where()` to do the exact same thing.

   `X['larger'] = np.where(X['Distance']>X['Threshold'],True,False)`

After using one of the above you can get the indices using `.index()`:

```
indices = X['larger'].index[X['larger']].values
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `np.where` here? isnt just `X['Distance']>X['Threshold']` enough?

Comment: @onyambu that's correct